# Changing from a non activity to an activity Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently developing a game app for my 2nd year project at uni, but i'm a little stuck on how i can move from a non-activity class to an activity. So my none activity class is a  quit screen within the game (yes i know you shouldn't use quit in a game but its one of my requirements), when i click on a button i want it to take me to the activity. (which basically thanks the user for playing and then exits the app) using System.exit(0) is just going back to the last activity visited.

The screen extends my Game Screen Class which is a parent class i created, this is the code for what happens when the user touches the 'yes' button in the quit screen:

```
@Override
public void update(ElapsedTime elapsedTime) {

 Input input = game.getInput();

    List<GameTouchEvent> touchEvents = input.getTouchEvents();

    if(touchEvents.size() > 0){
            GameTouchEvent touchEvent = touchEvents.get(0);

            if(yesButtonBound.contains((int) touchEvent.x, (int) touchEvent.y)){


               System.exit(0);


            }
```

I'm not looking for specific code answers as this is a project but any advice or hints would be very appreciated thanks!!

Comment: In the class the holds this code, do you have access to a Context (Activity, Service, Application)? Also, calling System.exit(0) actually quits the entire app. There is no taking you back to a previous Activity if you make that call.

Comment: Do you mean that calling "System.exit(0);" is not exiting your application?

Comment: There is no access to any of them, if i create an instance of context then it just throws errors that it is null. When i call System.exit(0) its just restarting the login activity?